# Ionic Framwork error when trying to add ios platform project

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, gulp

I was trying to create a new Ionic project and when I ran the command:

> ionic platform add ios

I got the following error at the end:

> Running command:
>   /Users/nnation/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>   /Users/nnation/myApp Error: spawn EACCES
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1162:11)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:100:31)
>       at runScriptViaChildProcessSpawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:188:23)
>       at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:131:16)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:114:20
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)

I am not sure what that ment, so i ran it again and I got the following:

> $ sudo ionic platform add ios running cordova platform add ios
>   Platform ios already added.

Thinking that everything is good i then ran:

> $ sudo ionic build ios

And then this happen again:

> running cordova build ios Running command:
>   /Users/nnation/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>   /Users/nnation/myApp Error: spawn EACCES
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1162:11)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:100:31)
>       at runScriptViaChildProcessSpawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:188:23)
>       at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:131:16)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:114:20
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)

Can someone assist me in figuring what is wrong or what i am missing? I am running MacOS.

Comment: `sudo ionic` ... **don't**! Make sure the permissions are correct and run the commands without `sudo`: `sudo chown -R nnation:staff /Users/nnation/myApp`

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem using `ionic hooks add`.

Found it [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-fix-this-error-spawn-eacces/20490/4)